# Webstorm - how do you find all typos?

Tags: webstorm

I'm using WebStorm 2018.2 and I have typos in my project:

[image]

How can I find all the typos in my project so I can go through them? I would really just like to see a whole list like global find does:

[image]

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000033264-View-All-Project-Errors-Warnings, or done other research?

Comment: @jonrsharpe that helps out, this wasn't the most intuitive way for me to find it. I tried a google search and had only found answers from 2016 like: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206917175-Find-all-spelling-errors from a google search for `webstorm find all typos`

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you post that as the answer, I'll gladly accept it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000033264-View-All-Project-Errors-Warnings

Going to `Code | Inspect Code` will find all spelling errors

[image: inspection scope]

Results in something like this:

[image: results]